# How to retain the value of an editable text field in a Lotus Notes form every time the user opens it?

Tags: forms, field, lotus-notes

I have a form in Lotus Notes containing an editable text field.

Once the user enters a value in that field, it gets saved properly when I check it by opening the document from the back-end.

But I need this value to be seen in the form every time the user opens the form.

Because it is a configuration form where the user should be able to see all the values saved.

For example, a field which contains the path to download a report. And it should be an editable field itself. Is there any way to do this? Any sort of clue or help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are mixing `Forms` and `Documents`. Please make cleared, what you want to achieve....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use @DbColumn in the default value of the editable text field of my form

Answer (score 1):

The value of an editable field stored in a document does keep it's value every time the user opens the document.

It sounds like you may ask for something else. You want User A to create a document, enter a value (i.g. a download path) and save the document. When User A or User B later creates another document based on the same form, the previously entered value should be the default. Is that what you mean?

In that case you could simply use @DbLookup or @DbColumn in the formula language in the Default Value property of the field.

Or create a lookup view with the previously created document, sorted descending by date, then use the GetFirstDocument method of the NotesView class to get the first document in that view and read the value out of it using the GetItemValues method of the NotesDocument class.

Performance tip: If you make sure the value you want to look up is visible in the lookup view you can use the GetFirstEntry method of the NotesView class, then use the ColumnValues property to get the value, this is much faster.

Comment: That is also one way to do it, yes.

Comment: Hi @Karl-HenryMartinsson Thanks for your response! But that was not my question.... My question is very simple. How to display that saved field value in the form itself? Every time whenever a user opens the form, I need that saved value to be seen in the form itself. Usually when you open a form, even though the editable text fields have a value saved in the document, it won't be seen in the form. That is what I want to achieve. That value should be seen in the form itself...

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a form and a document?
Let's user proper terminology. Users never opens a form, they open a  document. Forms are design elements.

Comment: Are you saying that when the user opens a document, the existing values stored in it are not being displayed? Then you have done something wrong, normally they do. 
Have you verified that the values are actually stored in the backend document? How did you do that? Did you look at the document properties?

Comment: @Karl-HenryMartinsson, Yes the value is stored in the backend document. I have seen it in the document properties. Now how do I make that saved value to be seen in the field of the form next time when the user opens that document through that form in the web? Hope I'm clear now..